# Computer running slow/weird. I'm not sure what the issue is

Tags: google-chrome, performance, speed

I have an OMEN 30L Desktop PC GT13-1000a. I've had it for about a year, playing videogames as well as doing schoolwork, and its been running very well up until recently. I have certain problems that are quite annoying, especially when doing schoolwork, but I can't seem to diagnose a concrete problem.

When I open up certain applications (chrome and discord as an example, but others as well), they run fine for a couple seconds, but then start abruptly lagging. For chrome, it makes it take a couple seconds to switch and open new tabs, drag to select text, and makes scrolling down a page very laggy. Weirdly enough, it also makes my mouse sensitivity feel abnormally high (?), as well as make my cursor movement feel laggy while moving it around with these applications on screen. I say on screen because when I minimize the application and return to my home screen, everything seems to turn normal, even with applications open. I also find it strange that most games on my computer (league of legends, valorant, overwatch) don't seem to lag at all, and actually run very well as expected of a PC.

I've only tested this recently, but solely steam games lag (might just be a problem with steam). On chrome, it seems that when I run a youtube video, all problems mentioned earlier go away when I'm on that specific tab and running the video (might not be a valid observation). Another really annoying problem I've been having is with my monitor (LG Ultragear) just shutting down after some inactivity, while my PC remains on. The fan turns off, the big omen square at the front of the PC starts flashing, and only some of the other lights in the PC remain on. My mouse and keyboard, as well as the power button to the PC, never work to fix this, and seemingly take no input.

The only way to fix this is to unplug the power cord to the PC and then plug it back in, which turns everything off like normal, but allows me to use the power button to start the PC. I'm not sure if the two issues I mentioned are related, but they both are super annoying to have to deal with. I've updated all my Nvidia drivers, reset my computer twice (one keeping some files, the other removing all), used support assist and Microsoft defender, which both didn't find any problems. Of course, none of these options worked in fixing anything.

One other observation that may be helpful is that even when I reset my PC, when configuring the startup, I experienced all the lag problems I mentioned earlier. When shutting down my PC, I can see lag in even the spinning loading element. If anyone has any sort of help they can give me, as well as suggestions for me as to what to do, it would be greatly appreciated. If any additional details are required, I will gladly respond.

Comment: I have an LG Ultragear monitor

Comment: You might try editing your post into manageable paragraphs.  Start with (a) full online and offline virus scans; (b) manufacturer's Hardware Diagnostic tests; and (c) manufacturer's Driver Updates; (d) if and only if a Hard Drive, defrag it.   Do a final restart and test.

Comment: Please break up your post into paragraphs.

Comment: Make backups of any and all important files. Then backup the backups.

Comment: I google searched your computer with the first result being [this](https://support.hp.com/gb-en/product/omen-30l-desktop-pc-gt13-1000a/2100404772/product-info) ... there's a one click fix for "PC slow or frozen" - have you seen that?

Answer (score 0):

From your last paragraph (thanks), run Hardware Tests, very particularly DISK.

If your hardware appears OK, you would be be best to fully back up and reinstall Windows (?) fresh and restore Apps and Backups.

If the hardware appears good, the symptoms point to either operating system damage or user profile damage or both. That is the main reason to suggest complete reinstall.

If hardware needs repair, get a shop to repair it (or maybe replace it) and again install Windows after repair.